# How do I enable the wireless card automatically without using fn + F5?

Tags: wireless, networking

I have a problem with my keyboard and I can not enable my wireless because the <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> does not work. I can enable the wireless card on Ubuntu without this key (<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)?

OS: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the terminal and put in

```
rfkill list
```

If it says "Soft blocked: Yes" then type in

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

If it says "Hard blocked: Yes" (which I think it will) see about enabling your card in the bios. Also check your fn key emulation in the bios as well.

Comment: unfortunately did not enable the command by the network card